# How could i package my java awt application with mysql database ?

Tags: java, mysql

I had created one java awt application ..and as its a standalone non install able jar program...it doesn't integrate any database with it...so is there any way to package/ integrate or bundle my java awt program with mysql database.

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by package? Do you want the program to connect with the mysql database?

Comment: I think he has data he needs in a database he wishes to distribute with the executable. Perhaps sqlite would be a good choice.